# Prepend string and Suffix sting to record using CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csv, export

I need to export Entities to a CSV File using CSVHelper. I made a trial work but I would have to write every field manually. What I want is to Write a record Prepended with either an 'H' or a 'D' and end every line with a single space. My Demo models:

```
PersonId    FirstName   LastName    DateOfBirth
1           Randy       Smith       1968-08-31 
2           Zachary     Smith       2002-01-10 
3           Angie       Smith       1969-11-20 
4           Khelzie     Smith       1996-07-27 

AutoId  Year    Make        Model                   OwnerId
1       2000    Toyota      4Runner                 1
2       1995    Ford        Mustang                 1
3       2014    Chevrolet   Corvette Stingray Coupe 2
4       2014    Volkswagen  Beetle Coupe            4
5       1980    Ford        F-150                   2
6       1968    Chevrolet   Camaro                  3
7       2000    Tonka       Truck                   3
8       1993    Honda       Accord                  4
```

Into a CSV File Like this:

```
H 1 Randy       Smith       8/31/1968 
D 1 2000        Toyota      4Runner 
D 2 1995        Ford        Mustang 
H 2 Zachary     Smith       1/10/2002 
D 3 2014        Chevy       Corevett 
D 5 1980        Ford        F-150
H 3 Angie       Smith       11/20/1969 
D 6 1968        Chevrolet   Camaro  
D 7 2000        Tonka       Truck 
H 4 Khelzie     Smith       7/27/1996 
D 4 2014        Volkswagen  Beetle Coupe
```

This is the Code I finally got to work:

```
        StreamWriter textWriter = File.CreateText(fileName);
        var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter);
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = delimiter;
        csv.Configuration.QuoteNoFields = true;

        // This will skip those people who don't own a vehicle
        foreach (Person person in people.Where(person => person.Vehicles.Count > 0))
        {
            // The letter 'H' must prefix every Header line
            csv.WriteField((@"H " + person.PersonId));
            csv.WriteField(person.FirstName);
            csv.WriteField(person.LastName);

            // Headers lines must end with a single space.
            csv.WriteField((person.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString() + " "));
            csv.NextRecord();
            foreach (Automobile auto in person.Vehicles)
            {
                // The letter 'D' must prefix every Detail line
                csv.WriteField((@"D " + auto.AutoId));
                csv.WriteField(auto.Year);
                csv.WriteField(auto.Make);

                // Details lines must end with a single space.
                csv.WriteField((auto.Model + " "));
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }
```

The real tables have ~70 fields apiece.

Comment: can you describe your issue?

Comment: @JossefHarush, O.K. well then, in summery is there a way to use WriteRecord() with a prefix and a suffix instead of a bunch of WriteField()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those that have as thick a skull as mine, here is a solution:

```
    foreach (TransactionHeader header in headers)
    {
        csv.WriteField("H");
        csv.WriteRecord(header);
        csv.WriteField(" ");

        csv.NextRecord();

        foreach (TransactionDetail detail in header.TransactionDetail)
        {
            csv.WriteField("D");
            csv.WriteRecord(detail);
            csv.WriteField(" ");

            csv.NextRecord();
         }             
     }
```

Thanks to everyone who saw this as pretty obvious and patiently waited for me to bash my head down on my desk enough times and then figure this out myself.